# Automatically parsing daily news XML files and displaying them on website

Tags: php, xml, drupal-6, ftp, feed

I have a news provider who deposits xml news files on my server via FTP every day. I need to automatically parse each day's files and display them on my Drupal website. I'm not even sure where to start... not sure how to instruct Drupal or PHP/MySQL to select the files automatically, parse them and display them. Any ideas? The XML structure is well-formed and never changes.

Thank you!

Jane

Comment: Drupal may have a plug-in for this already

Answer (score 1):

For xml parsing:

https://github.com/pvhee/feeds_xmlparser

Comment: Oh thank you, actually, now I'm thinking maybe "Feeds XPath Parser" (http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) is the way to go... I tried it some time ago with rather limited success, but now that I've dabbled in some XPath, maybe I'll have more luck with it...? Will check and post back.